# Bash script process name regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to regex process id's based on parts of a process name. It seems to work if I only do a single word, but it fails when I try to do something like: find me any process with path /beginning ****** /endswiththis/

Here's what I have so far:

```
QUEUE_PID="$(ps -ef | grep endswiththis | grep -v $0 | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')";
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many UNIXes now have `pgrep` which does exactly what you want

```
DESCRIPTION
   pgrep  looks  through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which
   matches the selection criteria to stdout.  All the criteria have to match.
```

As an example:

```
$ps -ef | grep sendmail
simonp    6004 27310  0 09:16 pts/5    00:00:00 grep sendmail
root      6800     1  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:03 sendmail: accepting connections
smmsp     6809     1  0 Jul19 ?        00:00:01 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue

$pgrep sendmail
6800
6809
```

The parameter passed to `pgrep` is a regular expression - this is matched against either against the executable file name or the full process argument string dependent on parameters (`-f`).

```
$pgrep  '^sen.*il$'
6800
6809

$pgrep -f '^sendmail.*connections$'
6800
```

For more information

```
man pgrep
```

Comment: Any thoughts on the regex to get anything that matches the beginning of the path and the end? /matchthis/ignore/ignore/andendwiththis/

Comment: @Steve: `grep '/matchthis/.*/andendwiththis/'` or `grep -E '/matchthis(/.*/|/)andendwiththis/'`

Comment: @Dennis that worked. I'm using variables for the matched terms and it seems to make it not work. Any syntax things that have to change?

Comment: @Steve: Change the single quotes `'` to double quotes `"` to allow the variables within to be expanded.

Comment: Sorry, I think I need to be more explicit. 
pathSite=sitex;
procVar=initQueues;
QUEUE_PID="$(ps -ef | grep '$pathSite.* $procName }' | grep -v $0 | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')";

Proc:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php /Projects/sitex/library/service/public/BackgroundService.php initQueues

Comment: Just watch out for the name limit. The above post mentions -f, but without this the pgrep match is truncated. Caught me out as I didn't note the significance. -l is great also to list the options.